# Flutter hive - retriving list of non-primitive datatypps

Tags: flutter, hive

I have a EventAdpator registered which holds my event data. I am reading data from an API and storing in Hive.

My Hive functions are like this

```
class HiveEvents { 
  static final eventsBox = Hive.box("eventsbox");

  static addEvent(Map data) {
    eventsBox.add(data);
  }

  static addEvents(List<Event> data) {
    eventsBox.addAll(data);
  }

  static List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    final data = eventsBox.keys.map((key) {
      final value = eventsBox.get(key);
      return value;  
    }).toList();

    return data;    // A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'getAllEvents' because it has a return type of 'List<Event>'.
  }
}
```

Previously, the data has been written to hive like this.

```
final Uri url = Uri.https(authority,path, queryParameters);
final http.Response result = await http.get(url);

if (result.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
  final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(result.body);
  final eventData = jsonResponse["events"];
  
  List<Event> events =
      eventData.map<Event>((i) =>
        Event.fromJson(i)).toList();

      HiveEvents.addEvents(events);

      return events;
} else {
  return [];
}
```

When trying to return the data from getAllEvents, this error is showing and I am unsure how to correct it.

> A value of type 'List' can't be returned from the method
> 'getAllEvents' because it has a return type of 'List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hive.box` is a generic method, so you need to call it with the expected type, which is `Event`.

```dart
class HiveEvents {
  static final eventsBox = Hive.box<Event>("eventsbox"); // (1) add <Event> here

  static addEvent(Map data) {
    // (2) You should convert Map to Event first before passing it to the add method. If Event is serializable, you can use the fromJson method
    eventsBox.add(data);
  }

  static addEvents(List<Event> data) {
    eventsBox.addAll(data);
  }

  static List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    final data = eventsBox.keys.map((key) {
      final value = eventsBox.get(key);
      return value!; // (3) add '!' here
    }).toList();

    return data;
  }
}
```

Additionally, you don't need to manually map the keys to values. You can use the `values` getter instead:

```
  static List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    final data = eventsBox.values.toList();

    return data;
  }
```